# MongoDB TTL expiry doesn't work properly on NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, caching, ttl

I'm using MongoDB (v3.4) as a cache and using TTL indexes to expire records. However, the TTL settings don't seem to work properly. Specifically, I tested using an endpoint to insert data (as below).

The endpoint mongoInsert is supposed to expire in 5 min. However, it seems that after ~1 min, the document got removed. I've looked up other similar suggestions regarding the use of UTC time using moment().utc().toDate(), and the behaviour was the same. new Date() returned UTC time so I guess it should be the same effect.

Not sure if there are other settings that should be included but are not detailed in the documentation. Anyone encountered this before?

```
function mongoInsert(mongoClient){
    return function(req, res){
        mongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/cache', function(err, db) {
            db.collection('data', function(err, collection){
                var testItems = [{
                    "_id": "abc12345",
                    "dmac": "abc",
                    "createdAt": new Date(),
                    "val": {
                        "0": 10,
                        "1": 15,
                        "2": 5
                    },
                    "res": "minutes",
                    "time": "2017-12-04T00:12:58Z"
                }];
                let unix = new moment().valueOf();
                collection.createIndex({createdAt: unix}, {expireAfterSeconds: 300});
                collection.insertMany(testItems, function(err, items){
                    db.close();
                    res.json(items);
                });
            })
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Please mention MongoDB version

Comment: I'm using Mongo version 3.4.

Comment: are you using mongoose.js ?

Comment: nope, not using mongoose, only the main mongodb package https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb

Comment: Using ensureIndex also doesn't work, the same behaviour is observed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
collection.createIndex({createdAt: 1}, {expireAfterSeconds: 60,unique:true});
```

and

```
collection.createIndex({createdAt: 1}, {expireAfterSeconds: 300,unique:true});
```

this is invalid

You cannot use createIndex() to change the value of expireAfterSeconds of an existing index. Instead use the collMod database command in conjunction with the index collection flag. Otherwise, to change the value of the option of an existing index, you must drop the index first and recreate.

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/core/index-ttl/

For expiry of individual documents, there are reports that it can only be done by calculating the expiry time and expiring them by a specific clock time (ref: groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-dev/ZLb8KSrLyOo).

```
var testItems = [{
    "_id": "abc12345",
    "dmac": "abc",
    "expireAt": moment().add(3, 'minutes').toDate(),
    "val": {
        "0": 10,
        "1": 15,
        "2": 5
    },
    "res": "minutes",
    "time": "2017-12-04T00:12:58Z"
}];
let unix = new moment().valueOf();
collection.createIndex({expireAt: unix}, {expireAfterSeconds: 0}, function(error, indexName){
    if(error) console.log(error);
    console.log(indexName);  
});
```

Comment: I'm not trying to change the value of expireAfterSeconds of an existing index. I'm trying to test out the functionality that both of them are dropped at different expiry times according to the TTL set. As it is, mongoDB is dropping my records way earlier than the set time of 300s.

Comment: you createIndex() twice on same "createdAt" key

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I already made the change but after changing it to a (unique) unix timestamp, it's still exhibiting the same (early expiry) behaviour.

Comment: u need to drop index first then apply time of 300 seconds again . please go through the link first

Comment: I'm sorry the two documents are so similar, but it's supposed to be 2 separate documents meant to expire at different times. Anyway I amended my question to be clear on what the issue is. There's no issue with index name conflicts. The issue here is with the expiry of TTL time..

Comment: for this u need to precalculate expiry time of each document
eg:"expiryTime"=createdAt"+60
and set expireAfterSeconds as 0 while creating index
collection.createIndex({expiryTime: 1}, {expireAfterSeconds:0,unique:true});
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-dev/ZLb8KSrLyOo

But I have never tried this , so u need to check this first

Comment: Hmm i guess I could try that out, but according to the official documentation it seems that there are 2 ways of expiring data, by seconds and by expiry time: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/tutorial/expire-data/

Comment: yes it is also saying same https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/tutorial/expire-data/#expire-documents-at-a-specific-clock-time